# We need a canonical "how do I add/modifyremove tags in my Tumblr theme" question

Tags: discussion, canonical-question

It seems to me that an awfully large percentage of questions about Tumblr are people trying to customize how or if tags appear in their posts. To wit:

**Deleted**

- https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/61011
- https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/60932
- https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/59655
- https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/58742
- https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/57866
- https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/56565
- https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/46422

**Duplicate**

- [How to make tumblr tags visible?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/55164)

**Open**

- [Tumblr theme tag block ignores first tag](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/55144)
- [How do you make tags on tumblr show only on hover?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/54998)
- [How do I remove tags from my Tumblr theme?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/53690)
- [Tumblr Theme HTML - Want Tags Below Post](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/52831)

(And that's just from the first page of [tagged questions](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tumblr).)

It seems to me that most if not all of these could be answered in much the same way. Unfortunately I'm not any sort of expert on Tumblr themes.

Would someone care to take a stab at creating a canonical question that we can then close most of these as a duplicate of? Or turn one of these into the best question and answer and make that a duplicate target? Or, at the very least, let's find and close the most egregious duplicates?

Comment: indeed.. I'll add a 250 rep bounty for canon question

Comment: One of those may need just a little tidying, going to have to see which one is best at pulling in the numbers